While i scrape website, can I search for specific keywords in a searchbar with Selenium (python)?
I need to scrape some pages using Selenium, and before I can scrape, I need to search for specific keywords inside the website and scrape all the content related to those keywords like this:
Website example
Problem is I can't always use boolean operator to search for all my keywords, so I need to search a keyword like "big data", scrape the content in the search page, clicking on all the url of the articles to scrape the full content, do this for all the articles then going back and search a new keyword.
I already have a code that is working for some websites I need to scrape, but it misses the part where I search for every keyword
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

def scrape_page(url):
    try:
        # Apri il sito web nel browser
        driver.get(url)
        driver.maximize_window()

        # Gestisci il banner dei cookie, se presente
        try:
            cookie_banner = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "")
            cookie_banner.click()
        except:
            pass

        # Imposta un intervallo di attesa esplicito per 10 secondi per garantire che la pagina sia completamente caricata
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        # Trova tutti gli elementi "Continua a leggere"
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "")
        # Lista per memorizzare i dati estratti
        data = []

        # Clicca su ciascun elemento
        for index, element in enumerate(elements):
            try:
                # Ottieni URL e titolo dell'articolo
                article_url = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "'(])["+str(index+1)+"]").get_attribute("href")
                article_title = element.find_element(By.XPATH, "'(])["+str(index+1)+"]").text
                # Clicca sull'elemento
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "'])["+str(index+1)+"]").click()
                # Ottieni il contenuto della landing page di "Continua a leggere"
                article_content = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "").text
                # Ottieni la data dell'articolo
                article_date = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "").text
                # Aggiungi i dati alla lista
                data.append({'Titolo': article_title, 'Data': article_date, 'URL': article_url, 'Contenuto': article_content})
                # Torna alla pagina precedente
                driver.back()
            except Exception as e:
                print("Errore durante il clic sull'elemento:", str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Errore durante lo scraping della pagina:", str(e))
        return None

    return data

# Crea un'istanza del driver del browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# URL del sito web da cui desideri effettuare il click
start_url = "https://www.salute.gov.it/portale/home.html"

# Lista per memorizzare tutti i dati estratti da tutte le pagine
all_data = []

# Cicla le pagine finché ci sono pagine successive
while start_url:
    print("Scraping:", start_url)
    page_data = scrape_page(start_url)
    if page_data:
        all_data.extend(page_data)
    
    try:
        # Cerca il link alla pagina successiva
        next_page_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "")
        # Estrae l'URL della pagina successiva
        start_url = next_page_link.get_attribute("href")
    except:
        # Se non ci sono più pagine successive, interrompe il ciclo
        start_url = None

# Chiudi il browser
driver.quit()

# Costruisci un DataFrame Pandas con tutti i dati estratti
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

# Visualizza il DataFrame
print(df)

df.to_excel("")

Can someone help my update my code?
Thank you in advance

I don't understand what if the problem. If you have many keywords then use for-loop to run code for every keyword separately.

maybe you should define function with extra parameter def scrape_page(url, keyword): and later run it in for keyword in all_keywords: scrape_page(url, keyword)

yeah but i need a function to search every keyword in the searchbar

I don't understand problem. use Selenium to find searchbar on page and use send_keys() to send text to this element, and to send Key.ENTER

But I need to search different keywords in different istances, so when i write the code i need to define a function to go back to the main page everytime i scraped the content related to the specific keyword

I still don't understand problem you can run for-loop which in first line runs driver.get(url) and every loop will start with main page. Frankly, my previous idea for keyword in all_keywords: scrape_page(url, keyword) also runs driver.get(url) for every keyword - so every keyword starts with main page.

I'm trying but I can't seem to find a solution, can i get an example code of how you would do it please?

To search:

first load main page
next find searchbar
next use send_keys() to send text to this searchbar,
and next use send_key() to send Keys.ENTER

It should redirect to page with results which has url driver.current_url
driver.get(start_url)

searchbar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "f_cerca")
searchbar.send_keys(word)
searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

print(driver.current_url)

And later you should run your function scrape_page() but without .get(url).
And you should run scrape_page() in loop with code which searchs link to next page - and it should use .get() to load this page (not do it in scrape_page(), and don't load main page.)
And all this code should be in for-loop which runs all code for different keywords.

Minimal working code with some changes:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

import time

# ---

import selenium
print('Selenium:', selenium.__version__)

# ---

def scrape_page(driver, keyword):
    try:

        # Gestisci il banner dei cookie, se presente
        try:
            print('Clicking cookie banner')            
            cookie_banner = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[b[text()='Chiudi']]")
            cookie_banner.click()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception:', e)

        # Trova tutti gli elementi "Continua a leggere"
        elements_dt = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "dl.simple-list.results dt")
        #elements_dd = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//dl[@class='sample-list.results']/dd/a")
        
        print('[DEBUG] len(elements_dt):', len(elements_dt))
        # Lista per memorizzare i dati estratti
        data = []

        # Clicca su ciascun elemento
        #for index, element_dt, element_dd in enumerate(zip(elements_dt, elements_dd), 1):  # you can use `enumerate(..., 1)` to start `index` with `1`
        for index, element in enumerate(elements_dt, 1):  # you can use `enumerate(..., 1)` to start `index` with `1`
            
            try:
                article_url = element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a').get_attribute("href")
                article_title = element.text
                
                # ... DON'T CLIK LINKS BECAUSE IT WILL REMOVE CURRENT PAGE FROM MEMPRY
                # ... AND YOU WILL LOST ACCESS TO OTHER `elements` ON CURRENT PAGE
                # ...
                # ... Get `href` and later (after loop) use `.get(href)` to access subpages. 
                
                data.append({
                    'keyword': keyword,
                    'Titolo': article_title, 
                    'URL': article_url, 
                    #'Data': article_date, 
                    #'Contenuto': article_content
                })
                
                print('[DEBUG] data:', data[-1])
                # Torna alla pagina precedente
                #driver.back()
            except Exception as e:
                print("Errore durante il clic sull'elemento:", e)
                
        # work with subpages

        for item in data:
            print('[DEBUG] subpage:', item['URL'])
            driver.get(item['URL'])
            #article_date = ...
            #article_content = ...
            #item['Data'] = article_date
            #item['Contenuto'] = article_content
             
    except Exception as e:
        print("Errore durante lo scraping della pagina:", e)
        return None

    return data

# --- main ---

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# ---

start_url = "https://www.salute.gov.it/portale/home.html"

all_data = []

keywords = ['ukraina', 'covid-19', 'elan musk']

for word in keywords:

    print("Main Page:", start_url)

    # open main page 
    driver.get(start_url)

    # find searchbar
    print('Search:', word)
    searchbar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "f_cerca")
    # put keyword in searchbar and press ENTER
    searchbar.send_keys(word)
    searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
    time.sleep(5) # wait for results
    
    #get current url (because it could load different URL to show results)
    search_results_url = driver.current_url
    
    # start scraping results (with pagination):
    #while True:  # try to get all pages
    for _ in range(3):  # try to get only 3 pages
        print("Scraping:", search_results_url)
        
        page_data = scrape_page(driver, word)  # <--- only scraping, without `.get(url)`, I send `word` only to add it to `data`
        
        if page_data:
            all_data.extend(page_data)

        driver.get(search_results_url) # go back to result after visiting subpages - to get link to next page 
        
        try:
            next_page_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Successive')]")
            search_results_url = next_page_link.get_attribute("href")
            driver.get(search_results_url)  # <--- open next page with results using URL
            #next_page_link.click()   # <--- or click link 
        except Exception as e:
            print('[DEBUG] Exception:', e)
            print('[DEBUG] break')
            #input('Press ENTER to continue')
            break  # exit loop
            
driver.quit()

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)

input("Press ENTER to close")


I've read your comments but I'd like to ask, when I copy the XPath of the article content I get the "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//" error, how can I fix that?

what XPATH? If you have error then you use wrong XPATH and you have to find correct XPATH. You shows error with "//" but it is not correct xpath - it needs something more.

I have tried taking the './/p' from this link https://www.salute.gov.it/portale/news/p3_2_2_1_1_stampa.jsp?id=564 , so I could extract the full article content

and what you get? I checked .//p in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox (using JavaScript Console and command $x('.//p')) and this page has 12 elements <p> - you have to use better xpath to get correct element. Maybe element has id or uniqe class or other value which you could use in xpath. But you don't have to use xpath - selenium allows also for By.CSS_SELECTOR and maybe it will be simpler for you.

If article content is in many <p> then maybe you should get all of them and later use for-loop to get .text from all of them and .join() them to one string.

Yes doesn't seem like I can get all the p with a unique id, I tried with xpath and css selector, but I'm not really getting the content of the articles, Thank you btw.

web pages are created for human and sometimes it is hard to scrape all data in one line. Sometimes it needs complex xpath, but sometimes it needs to get some part of HTML and later search data using Python - using string's functions or regex or count elements and get n-th element, or get element which is after other element, etc. So solution may need a lot of line of code.
